# A function like countifs in excel in python for multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to this community and hope that I can properly ask my question.
I have multiple dataframes, one of which is the main df having all customers with the `customer_id` as the key. As I want to analyze customers in different periods of their contracts, I'll define a `target_date` for each period; for example `target_date = order_date + timedelta(days=7)`. It is clear that each customer has a different order date and so the target date for each customer would be unique.

In other dataframes, I have different types of transactions stored. There will be always three columns in these dataframes: `c_id, trans_date, trans_type`. I want basically to go through each transaction_dataframe and count the number of transactions each customer performed before the `target_date` and **create a new column for each transaction type and store the count in the representative column.**

With help of some friends, I could find a solution that works perfectly when the data is not big enough! But my problem is I have more than 30K customers and 600K transactions and over 150 transaction types and I'm going to do my analysis in 4 different time periods, which requires massive calculations and my current solution is not efficient at all. In the following, I'll post my solution with some random data, but I want to ask if there is any way to improve calculation time.

Thanks in advance!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random

ID = [1,2,3,4,5]
target_date = [102,101,103,100,102]
users = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(ID, target_date)), columns =['ID', 'target_date'])
print("users:")
print(users)
#print("------")

users:
   ID  target_date
0   1          102
1   2          101
2   3          103
3   4          100
4   5          102

random_ID = []
for i in range(0,20):
  n = random.randint(1,5)
  random_ID.append(n)

random_tr= []
tr_list=['A','B','C','D','E','F']
for i in range(0,20):
  n = random.choice(tr_list)
  random_tr.append(n)

random_dt= []
for i in range(0,20):
  n = random.randint(100,104)
  random_dt.append(n)

transactions = pd.DataFrame({'ID':random_ID, 'Tr_type':random_tr, 'Date':random_dt})

transactions!!
    ID Tr_type  Date
0    3       B   102
1    1       A   101
2    3       A   101
3    2       E   101
4    1       B   101
5    5       A   104
6    1       E   100
7    5       B   102
8    2       D   101
9    3       F   104
10   2       D   102
11   2       B   103
12   4       A   100
13   1       F   101
14   2       E   100
15   3       C   101
16   1       D   102
17   1       C   102
18   2       E   102
19   1       B   104
```

---

```
all_user_tr = pd.DataFrame(columns=tr_list)
for index, row in users.iterrows():
  # print(row['ID'])
  user_ID = row['ID']
  Date_Compare = row['target_date']
  ID_tr = transactions.loc[transactions['ID'] == user_ID]
  ID_date = ID_tr.loc[ID_tr['Date'] <= Date_Compare]
  tr_count= ID_date['Tr_type'].value_counts() 
  count_tr_list = []
  cnt = 0
  for i in tr_list: 
    # print(i)
    if i in list(tr_count.index.values):
      count_tr_list.append(tr_count[i])
    else:
      count_tr_list.append(0)
    cnt=cnt+1

  # print(count_tr_list)
  current_id_df = pd.DataFrame([count_tr_list], columns=tr_list, index=[user_ID])
  # print(current_id_df)
  all_user_tr = all_user_tr.append(current_id_df)
all_user_tr.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
print("---")
print(all_user_tr)

---
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  1  1  1  1  1
1  0  0  0  1  2  0
2  1  1  1  0  0  0
3  1  0  0  0  0  0
4  0  1  0  0  0  0



res = pd.concat([users, all_user_tr], axis=1)
print('user')
print(res)

user
   ID  target_date  A  B  C  D  E  F
0   1          102  1  1  1  1  1  1
1   2          101  0  0  0  1  2  0
2   3          103  1  1  1  0  0  0
3   4          100  1  0  0  0  0  0
4   5          102  0  1  0  0  0  0
```